# Very slow query in Excel VBA using ADODB recordset to get prior value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this query in Access. It works very fast and with excellent performance.

But when I want to use this query in Excel using ADODB.REORDSET, it takes about 15 minutes to copy the record set information via `Range.CopyFromRecordset`

```
SELECT 
    d.ShamsiDate,
    d.UnitNo,
    d.[Counter_MVH+],
   (SELECT max( d1.[Counter_MVH+] )                
    FROM tblData AS d1                     
    WHERE d1.ShamsiDate < d.ShamsiDate AND d1.UnitNo = d.UnitNo
    ) AS PriorValue
FROM tblData d;
```

This is the code that used in VBA:

```
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, sq As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sq = _
    "SELECT d.ShamsiDate, d.UnitNo, d.[Counter_MVH+], " & _
        "(SELECT MAX(d1.[Counter_MVH+]) " & _
        "FROM [Data$] d1 " & _
        "WHERE d1.UnitNo = d.UnitNo AND d1.ShamsiDate < d.ShamsiDate ) AS PriorValue " & _
        "FROM [Data$] d;"

cn.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
cn.Open
rs.Open sq, cn, 3, 1

Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
cn.Close
```

Thank you. I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: 1. You are not querying Access you are querying an Excel workbook - Excel was never really designed to be used as a database
2. You are using a correlated sub-query (where the sub-query refers to the outer query) - these are generally considered as bad for performance. 
My advice is to find another way to do this

Comment: So do the query in Access. Then save the results in a file to use in Excel if you really have to.

Comment: I think there is a problem in the where clause in the sub query, I don't know how to solve it. If I remove it, it will be very fast

Comment: If you remove the where clause in your subquery you will have a VERY different query. Just the same, as others, noted, if your first query is ran in Access and your second query is run against Excel, I would DEFINITELY expect different performance. It would be silly to expect that excel/ace-OLDEB would have the same performance as Access, an actual database.

Comment: thanks for your attentions